# My webcams were mysteriously renamed to unhelpful names. How can I fix?

Tags: 20.04, usb, webcam

I've got two webcams: one of them is built in to my Lenovo T14s (running Ubuntu 20.04.3), and the other is an external USB device. They used to have obvious names: one was called something like "Integrated Camera C" and the other was called something like "HuddleCamHD". Strangely, they have both been renamed to be "Video Capture 4", which means I can't easily distinguish between them when switching cameras in tools such as Zoom or OBS Studio. Here's some output showing this:

```
$ v4l2-ctl --list-devices      
Video Capture 4 (usb-0000:00:14.0-5.2.3):
        /dev/video2
        /dev/video3

Video Capture 4 (usb-0000:00:14.0-8):
        /dev/video0
        /dev/video1
```

I have no idea why (or precisely when) this changed. Can anyone help me in either undoing this, or in renaming the webcams?